# Compare two cells with If clause in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to compare two numbers in two cells in excel. This is what i am trying to achieve but not able to

```
A1 = 100 (say)
B1 = 105 (say)
```

I want to find out if B1 is more than 10% of A1 or not.

This is what I have tried but in vain:

```
IF(A1="",0,IF(B1="",0,IF(B1>A1*1.1,TRUE, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

For your case:

if B1 is more than 10% of A1
*same as:*
if B1 is more than 11
Thus in **C1** enter:

```
=IF(OR(A1="",B1=""),"",IF(B1>0.1*A1,"yes","no"))
```

[image]